# How to replace only a part of the screen in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: replace, xamarin.android, screen

I have the following screen:

[image]

When clicking buttons `<<<` or `>>>` I want the part surrounded in red to be replace by something with the same structure(same widgets same alignment) but with different `TextView` values and `Table` values(only 2 buttons text stay the same). The part surrounded in red is an order which I get from orders.xml. This is not so relevant to my question. I say it to explain better my next question. If in that xml I have 3 orders ,when I open the screen, on screen appears first order, button `<<<` should be disabled, button `>>>` should be enabled. Then when I click button `>>>` on screen appears second order, both `<<<` and `>>>`
are enabled , then when I click `>>>` again, `>>>` becomes disabled , only `<<<` stays enabled, then when I click `<<<`, both  `<<<` and `>>>` are enabled and so on and so forth. I want the complete parts surrounded in red to be replaced when clicking  `<<<` and `>>>` not only its text so user has the feelig that this is diffrent order from the previous one because if I change only its text he may not notice that. Doing all that with as little code as possible will be appreciated. You can change the title of the question ,that was the best I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing parts of the screen is a perfect use-case for fragments. Take a look into them at the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).